# What is the name of the previous Air Traffic Management System (ATMS) of Hong Kong International Airport?

Tags: air-traffic-management

Hi I really need help for the question.
The current ATMS for Hong Kong International Airport is the AutoTrac III, but does anyone know what is Hong Kong's Previous ATMS?

Comment: Could it be the AutoTrac II? And where have you checked already? Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: I have checked through their Civil Aviation Department and little information about their previous ATMS. I have yet contacted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [AutoTrac I](https://www.faama.org/2016/10/28/what-are-the-problems-affecting-hong-kongs-new-air-traffic-control-system-from-south-china-morning-post/), also from Raytheon.

Comment: Oh, thank you! If possible, do you have the specs about the AutoTrac I? (such as the Primary surveillance radar & Secondary surveillance radar ranges and their respective rotation rate, etc.) If unable to provide, then it is alright. Thank you again, as now at least I have a lead for my research.